# many to many relationship in django and templates

Tags: django, templates, models

I have three models: Zone, Stage and ZoneStage with ManyToMany relationship.

the whole point behind is that I have multiple Zone and each Zone has multiple Stages. For each Zone for each Stage I want to display certain VALUE and this is why I create ZoneStage model.

I do not know how to display values as per pictures below. I thought I could do it via:

e.g.
for objectz in zone:
 for objects in stage:
   for objectzs in zone_stage:

and here some conditions

or

e.g.
to try with filters ?

Although, I need some guidance and direction what to read about, how to do it etc and I would appreciate any help with any feedback that can make my life easier to solve this problem.

This is what I get:

[image]

My Models:

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    ZONE_N = (
        ('Z2','Z2'),
        ('Z4','Z4'),
        ('Z6.1','Z6.1'),
        ('Z9LH','Z9LH'),
        )
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ZONE_N, primary_key=True)
    zone_number = models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('zone_name',)      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.zone_name    

class Stage(models.Model):
    STAGE_N = (
        ('S1','S1'),
        ('S2','S2'),
        ('S3','S3'),
        ('S4','S4'),
        )    
    stage_number = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STAGE_N, primary_key=True)
    stage_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zones = models.ManyToManyField('Zone', through='ZoneStage', related_name='status')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('stage_number',)      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stage_number       

class ZoneStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('zone',)          

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.zone, self.stage)
```

My Views:

```
def index(request):
    zs = ZoneStage.objects.all()
    z = Zone.objects.all()
    s = Stage.objects.all()
    context = {'zone_stage': zs, 'zone': z, 'stage': s}

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

My Template:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    {% for object in zone %}
    <td>{{ object.zone_name }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

{% for stages in stage %}
<tr>
<td>{{ stages.stage_number }}</td>
<td>{{ stages.stage_name }}</td>
        {% for values in stages.zonestage_set.all|dictsort:"zone.zone_name" %}
        <td>{{ values.value}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ZoneStage` is an `intermediate` model, the `zoneid` and `stageid` should be `ForeignKey`, not `ManyToMany`. See example here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

If you look at your structure, you'll see that it makes sense. Since your `ZoneStage` are intersection points, they can't be many to many. Each `ZoneStage` will have one unique `Zone` and one unique `Stage`.

Once this is done, you could access the values this way for example:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ object.zone }}</td>
    {% for object in zone|dicsort:"zone_name" %}
        <td>{{ object.zone_name }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% for objectS in stage %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ objectS.stage_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ objectS.stage_name }}</td>
            {% for zonestages in objectS.zonestage_set.all|dictsort:"zoneid.zone_name" %}
                <td>{{ zonestages.zonestage}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

EDIT:

Previous solution works if every intersection has a value. If not one other way to do it would be like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ object.zone }}</td>
        {% for object in zone|dicsort:"zone_name" %}
            <td>{{ object.zone_name }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% for objectS in stage %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ objectS.stage_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ objectS.stage_name }}</td>
                {% for zones in zone|dicsort:"zone_name" %}
                    <td>
                    {% for zonestages in objectS.zonestage_set.all %}
                    {% if zonestages.zone == zones %} {{ zonestages.zonestage}}{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: hi, I have changed my code as per updated code in my first post above and followed your advice with dictsort but still do not display the values ...

Comment: to use '_set', you need to use the model name. So it should be: {% for values in stages.zonestage_set.all|dictsort:"zone.zone_name" %}. Apart from that I think it should work but without seeing the data it's a bit hard to tell. Is the rest of your table showing?

Comment: Julien, thanks for your advice. Your answer first pointed me to the right direction and now you further advice allows me to see values although I do not display them as expected. I will post a picture in a second.

Comment: I understand now I need to add {% if %} statement to test some conditions if there is ZoneStage for that Zone for that Stage to display value {% else %} display for example None.

Comment: yes, my example works if there is a zonestage value for each intersection point. If not, as I now understand is the case, you need a different logic. You could iterate all zones for all stages and use {% if %} statement to check if the zone stage is linked to both. And depending on your whole setup, maybe it would be simpler to provide zonestage values for all intersection. If your application relies a lot on these zonestages, it may be pertinent to be able to check if a specific intersection has or hasn't a zonestage.

Comment: I can see it would be much simpler just to set zonestage by default to 0% but it means I need to create zonestage by default even if I do not need it. My problem is I do not know how to check if there is zonestage object linked to both and display its value in right intersection point if such zonestage exists. I think I will try to work out this **"to check if a specific intersection has or hasn't a zonestage."**

Comment: See edit I added an example on how you could work out the table. Maybe not the most efficient but it should give you an idea.